# looking for form file transfer done event! jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, file

I'm doing a file upload with "PECL uploadprogress" status while using a "beforeunload" warning if user try to close window, which is activated on summitting.

```
$('#form').click(function() {
    $('#upload').submit();
    ajaxd();    
    setInterval("ajaxd()",1000);

    (...)

    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
    /*  return true || confirm("Do you really want to close?"); */
        return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
    }); 
}

function ajaxd() {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    (...) // get and workaround progress for upload-bar
    });
}
```

Now I need to UNBIND the "beforeunload" somewhere ...

```
$(window).unbind();
```

... but where? $.ajax({ }).done or .complete does not work here, because the function is repeating. Also .ajaxStop. I need an event at "file transfer done", to unbind. I could use something like

```
if $progress_percent > 90 { unbind() }
```

(when file-transfer is done, the form follows the target (action). the page will close. probably before the script got 100%. the user gets a warning at this unload. that's what i try to avoid by using >90 instead of ==100.)

but I don't like this way. Got any better solution?

Comment: Rather than unbinding the beforeunload, store the percent done in a gobal variable and default it to 100%, then when the event happens, test whether or not the percent is your value and either return a string or nothing ( do not `return true;`, just `return;` )

Comment: @kevin, for real i use an ID here. $('#form_submit_button'). just want to make it understandable.

if the file-transfer is done, the form follows the target. the page will close. probably, before the script got 100%. in this case, the user gets a warning. that's what i try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you had used [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php), the JavaScript event would've been unbound in case when  `$_SESSION["upload_progress_xxx"]["done"]` is true, or an upload error detected.